Using dbeaver and postgresql can I declare a variable INTERVAL to pass into a sproc?
I have a PostgresSQL table that has a field for TIMESTAMP, and an associated stored procedure that takes an INTERVAL and calculates the difference from now() + in_interval. I want to use dbeaver to test but can't figure out how to accomplish this.
I have tried setting a variable eg @set interval = now() + 'INTERVAL 1 MINUTE' and using that with :interval
Using a nested select
SELECT insert_event('event_type', (select (now() +  interval '1 minute')));
And a few other things I have lost but I keep getting errors. Is this possible?
CREATE TABLE events (
    event      TEXT
    event_time TIMESTAMP
); 

And a sproc
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_event(
    in_event     TEXT
    in_interval  INTERVAL

)
RETURNS void
AS $$
DECLARE
    v_now                   TIMESTAMP := now() at time zone 'utc';
    v_end_time              TIMESTAMP := v_now + in_interval;
BEGIN
    ...use the value later on...
END



Asking for help with errors and not showing the actual errors seems counterproductive.

I did the following (fiddle here):
CREATE TABLE events 
(
    event      TEXT,
    event_time TIMESTAMP
);

and then:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_event
(
    in_event     TEXT,
    in_interval  INTERVAL
)
RETURNS TIMESTAMPTZ  -- Changed return type!
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    v_now                   TIMESTAMP := now() at time zone 'utc';
    v_end_time              TIMESTAMP := v_now + in_interval;
  BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT NOW() + in_interval);  -- Dummy!
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

and we use our function
SELECT 
  insert_event('event_type', '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL);

Result:
insert_event
2024-05-04 22:58:07.781712+00  -- correct at time of running!

this also works
SELECT
  insert_event('Blah', INTERVAL '1 MONTH');

Et voilà! Nothing to do with DBeaver!
For starters, your declaration
@set interval = now() + 'INTERVAL 1 MINUTE'

is MySQL or SQL Server syntax (? or a mix), and more importantly, what you appear to be doing is creating a session variable in psql and not anything that can be used by DBeaver.
In psql, you can do the following:
\set the_int '''1 MONTH''::INTERVAL'

Note the ''' - escaping the quoted bits! And then you can test your function as follows:
test=# SELECT insert_event('blah', :the_int);
         insert_event          
-------------------------------
 2024-05-05 01:04:38.551313+01

Works fine! Note the : in front of the_int.
For quick ad-hoc testing of your function, you could do something like this - the insert_event_bis() function actually INSERTs a record into the events table - see fiddle:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_event_bis
(
    in_event     TEXT,
    in_interval  INTERVAL
)
RETURNS void
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    v_now                   TIMESTAMP := now() at time zone 'utc';
    v_end_time              TIMESTAMP := v_now + in_interval;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO events VALUES (in_event, NOW() + in_interval);
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;

and then:
WITH cte (int_val) AS
(
  SELECT '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL AS int_val
)
SELECT insert_event_bis('Blah_cte_test', (SELECT c.int_val FROM cte c));

and then to check:
SELECT * FROM events;

Result:
event          event_time
Blah           2024-05-05 00:21:58.057688
Blah_cte_test  2024-05-05 00:21:58.061262  -- cte record inserted!   

Can also do, in the body of the function (see last snippets of fiddle):
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO events VALUES (in_event, v_end_time);
END;

These will work with DBeaver!
